# MVC5 razor view dosen't display Bootstrap DataTable with @foreach Loop

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, foreach, razor-pages

I want to get a line like this with MVC5 @foreach method and dataTables.

[image: Example]

Here is the index.cshtml file.

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Optionen
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Position)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Office)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Office)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#example').DataTable();
     });
}
}
```

The line with 'Show [ ] entries' and 'Search [  ] ' doesen't appear but the rest of the table.

If there is no foreach loop in the table it works. Has someone an idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo need to make sure the number of `<th>` in `<tr>` is the same with the number of `<td>` in `<tr>`.Here is a demo:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Office)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

result:
[image]